# Powershell - Loop script until user chooses to exit

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

How can I start a script over again?  I have 3 switches and I want them to revert back to the beginning of the script.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Write-Host "--Please Login using a.account--"
#login
$credential = Get-Credential
#Main
Write-Host "--Remote Computer Rename v2.0--"
Write-Host "1. Query AD (Outputs to a text file)"
Write-Host "2. Quick computer rename"
Write-host "3. Quit"
$choice=Read-Host "Chose a number to continue"

#AD Query for computer
switch ($choice)
{
 1 {
Write-Host "--Enter first five characters of computer name or full computer name i.e.     USCLT--"
$cn=Read-Host 'Computer name'
$out="$cn*"
Get-ADComputer -Filter 'SamAccountName -like $out' >> c:\myscripts\dsquery.txt
Write-Host "Query complete.  See dsquery.txt saved to Desktop."
}

...rest of my code.
```

So after *See dsquery.txt saved to Desktop."* I want it to go back to write-host portion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My personal favorite for checking user input is the `do { } until ()` loop. Here is your code with the added loop, this will accomplish what your looking for:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Write-Host "--Please Login using a.account--"
#login
$credential = Get-Credential
#Main
do {
Write-Host "--Remote Computer Rename v2.0--"
Write-Host "1. Query AD (Outputs to a text file)"
Write-Host "2. Quick computer rename"
Write-host "3. Quit"
$choice=Read-Host "Chose a number to continue"

#AD Query for computer
switch ($choice)
{
 1 {
Write-Host "--Enter first five characters of computer name or full computer name i.e.     USCLT--"
$cn=Read-Host 'Computer name'
$out="$cn*"
Get-ADComputer -Filter 'SamAccountName -like $out' >> c:\myscripts\dsquery.txt
Write-Host "Query complete.  See dsquery.txt saved to Desktop."
}

...rest of my code.
} until ($choice -eq 3)
```

This is a pretty unique strategy in my opinion. I took this from Jerry Lee Ford’s book : Microsoft Windows PowerShell Programming for the absolute beginner

you can read more about these and every other loop in powershell here : http://www.powershellpro.com/powershell-tutorial-introduction/logic-using-loops/

Answer (score 7):

Simple, short, stupid:

```
& cmd /c pause
exit
```

This will even contribute the "Press any key" message the TO requested. If you prefer to stay in PowerShell:

```
Read-Host "Press any key to exit..."
exit
```

But we may also get the input back:

```
$reply = Read-Host "Please type EXIT to exit"
if ($reply -eq "EXIT") { exit; }
```

I like that `Read-Host` exits the script when typing Ctrl-C, like cmd's `pause` does.

Comment: But `Read-Host "Press any key to exit..."` allows the user to type anything before pressing `enter` to exit.  So it really should be `Read-Host "Press the enter key to exit..."`.  That said, what is the command to exit when `"any key"`  is pressed?

Answer (score 2):

From a [blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-use-powershell-to-wait-for-a-key-press/) I found:

```
echo "Press any key to exit..."
$Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho, IncludeKeyDown") | OUT-NULL
$Host.UI.RawUI.FlushInputbuffer()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the whole thing in a `while (1) {}` block. That creates an infinite loop that will only terminate if it encounters a **break** (end the loop) or **exit** (end the script). Presumably, option 3 will lead to one of those statements.